# How to set Redshift parameter permantly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How could I set the redshift cluster parameter permantly ?

for example

```
set search_path to '$user', public, dev;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it via the [Redshift parameter group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-parameter-groups.html#default-param-group-values) under search_path